# How to find the rolling average.. Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS' error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the rolling average of a column that I have made names "Total Vehicles". The code seems to make sense to me, but I keep getting an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
> Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'

The code that I have been trying is:

```
SELECT              
        CAST(TRANS_DATE_TIME as DATE) Date              
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER = 0 THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "HOV"              
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 1 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 15300             
                OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 30000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 55999              
                OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 65000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 199999             
                   THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER 
                   ELSE NULL 
               End) as "ExpressPass"                
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 15301 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 29999             
                   OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 56000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 64999               
                   OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 200000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 299999             
                   THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER 
                   ELSE NULL 
               End) as "CDecal"             
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER > 299999 THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER 
                    ELSE NULL 
                End) as "Unknown"               
        ,COUNT (HOV_TAG_NUMBER ) as "Total Vehicles"        
        ,AVG("Total Vehicles") OVER (ORDER BY Trans_Date_Time ASC ROWS 6 PRECEDING) AS RollingAvg                       
FROM 
    [DMS].[dbo].[VEHICLE_TRANSACTION]               
WHERE 
    TRANS_DATE_TIME >= '2019-01-01'                     
GROUP BY 
    CAST(TRANS_DATE_TIME as DATE)       
ORDER BY 
    Date
```

I have tried different variations of the order of (`ORDER BY Trans_Date_Time ASC ROWS 6 PRECEDING`), but I continually get the same rows error.

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: are you sure this works? >> ,AVG("Total Vehicles") ?? I'm thinking you may need a cte to calculate the rolling average using the derived Total Vehicles column. Then try  ,AVG([Total Vehicles]) OVER (ORDER BY Date ASC ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RollingAvg

Comment: I don't see a problem with this query in the `OVER` clause, however you can't take the `AVG` of `Total Vehicles` as it is a column alias which is not defined at the time.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a column alias as part of Average call. It is not permitted.

```sql
 ,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER > 299999 THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER 
                    ELSE NULL 
                End) as "Unknown"               
        ,COUNT (HOV_TAG_NUMBER ) as "Total Vehicles"  -- Alias Name       
        ,AVG("Total Vehicles") OVER (ORDER BY Trans_Date_Time ASC ROWS 6 PRECEDING) AS RollingAvg    -- Using alias name in the AVG function call
```

What you have to use instead is, use subquery for derived table and then calculate Average on top of "Total Vehicles".

```sql
SELECT [Date],ExpressPass,CDecal,Unknown,"Total Vehicles",
  ,AVG("Total Vehicles") OVER (ORDER BY Trans_Date_Time ASC ROWS 6 PRECEDING) AS RollingAvg 
FROM
(
SELECT             
        CAST(TRANS_DATE_TIME as DATE) Date              
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER = 0 THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER ELSE NULL End) as "HOV"              
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 1 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 15300             
                OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 30000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 55999              
                OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 65000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 199999             
                   THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER 
                   ELSE NULL 
               End) as "ExpressPass"                
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 15301 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 29999             
                   OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 56000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 64999               
                   OR HOV_TAG_NUMBER >= 200000 and HOV_TAG_NUMBER <= 299999             
                   THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER 
                   ELSE NULL 
               End) as "CDecal"             
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER > 299999 THEN HOV_TAG_NUMBER 
                    ELSE NULL 
                End) as "Unknown"               
        ,COUNT (HOV_TAG_NUMBER ) as "Total Vehicles"        
                           
    FROM [DMS].[dbo].[VEHICLE_TRANSACTION]              
   WHERE TRANS_DATE_TIME >= '2019-01-01'                        
   GROUP BY CAST(TRANS_DATE_TIME as DATE)  ) as t
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Comment: This is not the problem. See the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Nick, Sorry . I was wrong. I again verified the issue and updated my answer.

Comment: Does anyone know how to find a rolling avg in the 2008 version of SQL Server?

Comment: @mohlensehlen, please tag the question correctly for the version of sql server. It will save efforts of answers

Comment: @mohlensehlen, I would suggest you to ask separate question, as modifying question, will lead to confusion